# Bootstrap3 grid - 2 background colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make an effect like in the image below?

I want to have a container with 2 columns. The smaller column should be on yellow background and the bigger column on white. The yellow color should be from the left side and finish at right end of `col-xs-4`.

[image: Example]

Comment: give class in your css like .container .col-xs-4{ background-color:yellow }

Comment: Then background will be only on this column, but should start from left side of body. Conrtiner is not fluid as you see !

Comment: If you are using a container class having two columns means there is no space from left side. Please explore the question.

Comment: There can be space at the left side, he is not using fluid container

Comment: are you sure your `col-xs-4` is close in `container` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a pseudo-element.

Note the general layout method here is not important (I used flexbox for practice) but the pseudo-element technique is a common one.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}
.container div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.left {
  width: 25%;
}
.right {
  width: 75%;
}
/* MAGIC */

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* prevent scrollbars */
}
.left {
  position: relative;
  /* positioning context */
}
.left:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  /* half viewport width */
  height: 100%;
  /* parent height */
  background: orange;
  z-index: -1;
  /* push under parent */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: GREAT ! This method is fine for me. Thanks.